# Python: using a function inside a function?

Tags: python

So for an assignment I have to create a bunch of different functions in one Python file. One of the functions calls for inputting a list (sorted_list) and a string from that list (item). What the function does is reads the list and removes any duplicates of the specified string from the list.

```
def remove_duplicates(sorted_list, item):
    list_real = []
    for x in range(len(sorted_list)-1):
        if(sorted_list[i] == item and sorted_list[i+1] == item):
            list_real = list_real + [item]
            i+1
        else:
            if(sorted_list[i] != item):
                list_real = list_real + [sorted_list[i]]
        i+=1
    return list_real
```

So 
`remove_duplicates(['a','a','a','b','b','c'] 'a')` would return `['a','b','b','c']`

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do something like this, but that isn't my problem.

The next function I have to define is similar to the one above except it only takes sorted_list and it has to remove duplicates for each item instead of a specified one. The only thing I know is that you have to use a for loop that makes the remove_duplicates run for each item in a given list, but I have no idea how to actually implement a function inside of another function. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You just do it. There is no special syntax for writing a function inside another function. You just write it like any other block of code. It's no different than having an if statement indented inside another if statement, or another for loop nested inside an outer one.

Answer (score -1):

This works nicely:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse

def remove_duplicates(sorted_list, item):
    idx = sorted_list.index(item)
    list_real = sorted_list[:idx+1]
    if len(list_real) != len(sorted_list):
        for item in ifilterfalse (lambda x: x is item, sorted_list[idx:]):
            list_real.append(item)
    return list_real
```

Comment: Importing itertools seems way over the top for someone who doesn't understand functions